# Linking Access table to Outlook contacts - not showing custom fields

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am facing the situation that linking by ODBC connection is not enough for linking custom fields.

I know there are many articals here and in general, but nothing helped me.

Can someone please show me some light to find a proper code to link also specific fields, so I could just modify the name of the fileds and the address of the files. I have exprience with VBA for ACCESS and Excel but unfurtantly not enough with Outlook objects...

Also a way to keep the structure of special data type, like lookup wizards with multiple choices, Yes/No tick box, input masks and inpus masks.

Thanks a lot!

[this solution didn't help....](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4e63d48d-670b-49b5-8c4a-19dcb860d756/access-link-table-with-outlook-problem?forum=isvvba)

You all have a great week!

Cheers

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Any link will not contain custom fields, as you've already discovered. You'll have to use the **Outlook Object Model**. With this, you can full control of Outlook, including all data.

You'll have to dig through the documentation as I don't have an example for you, [but here's a start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms268893.aspx).